# Preg_replace() to add to string using non-capturing group

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, capturing-group

I have a piece of HTML markup, for which I need to add a specific CSS rule to it. The HTML is like this:

```
<tr>
<td style="color:#555555;padding-top: 3px;padding-bottom: 20px;">In order to stop receiving similar emails, simply remove the relevant <a href="https://domain.tld/dashboard/" target="_blank">saved search</a> from your account.</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see `td` already contains a `style` tag, so my idea is to match the last `;` of it and replace it with a `;` plus the rule I need to add...

The problem is that, although I used the appropriate non-capturing group, I still can't figure out how to do this properly... Take a look at this experiment please: https://regex101.com/r/qlVq6A/1

```
(<td.*style=".*)(;)(".*>)(?:In order to stop receiving)
```

On the other hand, when I assign a capturing group to the last part (the text in English that's there just to identify which `td` I'm interested in) it works OK, but I feel like this is an indirect way to make this work... Take a look at this experiment: https://regex101.com/r/qhVatN/1

```
(<td.*style=".*)(;)(".*>In order to stop receiving)
```

Can someone explain to me why the first route doesn't work? Basically, why the non-capturing group still captures the text inside of it...

Comment: Do you have to use a regexp? It would be better to use a DOM parser and then just update the attribute.

Comment: Please post your code here, not just a link to regex101.com. If the question is about `preg_replace()`, show the PHP code.

Comment: Your first link doesn't try to add anything to the style. All it does is remove the text in the non-capturing group.

Comment: I think you're confusing a non-capturing group with a lookahead. Non-capturing groups are included in the match, so they get replaced by the replacement.

Comment: "why the non-capturing group still captures the text inside of it" What makes you think it's capturing anything? "Capture" in this context means that you can reference it later with `$<number>` to copy it to the replacement.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, every time I tried to use a DOM parser, it was a complete waste of time, as it over-complicated things, plus there are many voices saying that it's not even the correct way to do this... Anyway, about embedding the code here, you're right, and I'll do so. About the first example, not adding anything, I stopped it halfway, because the _In order to stop..._ part that was matched/captured was getting lost... That's why I tried the second method with the multiple capturing groups, which works as intended. But still I can't figure out why the other approach doesn't work...

Comment: @Barmar now that you mention it, I may have confused the negative lookahead with the non capturing group... And indeed in my head they were very close to their functionality... I'm not a regexp expert. I'm using it rarely when I have to deal with situations like this mostly...

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/OYhOko/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second pattern, you use 3 capture groups and you use the style that you want to add in the replacement and the 3rd group contains `In order to stop receiving` which will be present after using group 3 in the replacement.

But in your first pattern, you use a non capture group `(?:` and that will **match** but is not part of the replacement.

Note that when using a non capture group like that you can just omit it at all because the grouping by itself like that without for example a quantifier or alternation has no additional purpose.

You can use a pattern for the example string, but this can be error prone and using a DOM parser would be a better option.

A way to write the pattern with just 2 capture groups:

```
(<td[^>]*\bstyle="[^"]*;)([^"]*">In order to stop receiving)
```

In the replacement use:

```
$1font-size: 80%;$2
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `<td[^>]*` Match `<td` and then optionally repeat any char except `>`
  - `\bstyle="[^"]*;` Match `style="` and then optionally repeat matching any char except `"` and then match the last semicolon (note that it is part of group 1 now)
- `)` Close group 1
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^"]*">In order to stop receiving` Optionally repeat matching any char except `:` and then match `">` followed by the expected text
- `)` Close group 2

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GlzD99/1).

---

Another option to write the pattern without capture groups making use of `\K` to forget what is matched so far, and a positive lookahead `(?=` to assert the expected text to the right:

```
<td[^>]*\bstyle="[^"]*;\K(?=[^"]*">In order to stop receiving)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zF6rkk/1).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer, and also for improving the wording of my question itself!